# Set internal IP range on devstack

Tags: openstack, devstack

How do I set the range of internal IPs VMs can have allocated on a devstack instance? I can't seem to find anywhere in the GUI. When I set it up initially in the local.conf I set:

```
FLAT_INTERFACE=eth1
FIXED_RANGE=10.2.3.0/24
NETWORK_GATEWAY=10.2.3.251
```

However it seems to ignore this and VMs are appearing on 10.0.0.x.

Comment: Probably better to ask this in either ServerFault or ask.openstack.org.

Comment: OK. Have done now (http://serverfault.com/questions/626568/set-internal-ip-range-on-devstack). I thought here might be better as there's the devstack tag which isn't present on serverfault (they just have openstack).

Comment: Did you re-run `stack.sh` after making the configuration changes? I believe you made the correct change, but this is not something that can be changed dynamically, the easiest way is to rerun the installer to start from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I did try to re-run `stack.sh` but it didn't work. So I made a clean install, changed the `local.conf` as mentioned and then ran `stack.sh` but I still had the problem as outlined above.

Answer (score 3):

Let me explain 4 networking parameters you should have in local.conf.

```
local.conf
# FIXED_RANGE is used by internal subnet which is by default 'private'.
FIXED_RANGE=172.23.1.0/24
# NETWORK_GATEWAY is address of gateway connects internal to external.  
NETWORK_GATEWAY=172.23.1.1
# FLOATING_RANGE is used by external subnet which is by default 'public'
FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.0.0/24
# PUBLIC_NETWORK_GATEWAY is external gateway.
PUBLIC_NETWORK_GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
```

Its a bit confusing. FIXED_RANGE is used for internal subnet therefore VMs are appering on FIXED_RANGE.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the other 2 parameters. I will have to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue:
First unstack it using "./unstack.sh"
Put those  configuration lines in "devstack/localrc" file and then do "./stack.sh".